# Why does IntelliJ Idea offer to enclose a string literal to triple double quotes?

Tags: string, scala, intellij-idea, quotes

While using IntelliJ Idea to code Scala I've noticed it to use to offer to enclose a string literal in a second pair of double quotes. «Convert to """string"""» - it says. If I agree - it just adds a 2 more double quote marks before and 2 more after the string, having my string to look like

```
val myString = """my string value"""
```

How does this make any sense? Do triple double quotes mean something special in Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [IntelliJ smart String](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2011/04/29/smart-strings/), there should be only two cases.

- simple string (which you can convert to triple double-quotes multi-line String literal)
- multi-line String literal, introduced way back in [Scala 2.1.7](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/43#2.1.7) (which you can convert back to a single String)

So when you see this:

[image: convert to multi-line String literal]

you should end up with `"""`. If not, this should be reported as a bug in the [youtrack Scala project](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/SCL).

---

But **if there were triple double quotes**, then IntelliJ correctly transformed your simple String into a multi-line String literal, which, as [illustrated by langref](http://langref.org/scala/strings/declaring-strings/multiline), allows you to define:

```
val text = "This\nIs\nA\nMultiline\nString"
```

into

```
val text = """This
Is
A
Multiline
String"""
```

[Rosetta code mentions](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Literals/String#Scala) the behavior has changed between Scala 2.7 and 2.8:

> on version 2.7, the triple-double-quoted string ends at the third consecutive quote, on version 2.8 it ends on the last quote of a series of at least three double-quotes.

Scala 2.7:

```
scala> val error = """can't finish with a quote: """"
<console>:1: error: unterminated string
       val error = """can't finish with a quote: """"
                                                    ^
```

Scala 2.8

```
scala> val success = """but it can on 2.8: """"
success: java.lang.String = but it can on 2.8: "
```

Comment: There were indeed triple quotes, I just didn't see that right. As far as I understand, you know what does that mean - so you can edit your question to only explain what do triple quotes mean and I will accept it. I've already got it, but I think it'd be better to do so.

Comment: @Ivan: ok,  I have added some example and definition for multi-line String literal.

Answer (score 0):

Triple quotes are used to contain raw strings.

A raw string can contain any character, including newlines (as illustrated by @VonC) but also escape sequences in general.

One common usage is in simplifying regular expression patterns, for example:

```
val Date = """((\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d{4}))|((\w{3}) (\d\d),\s?(\d{4}))""".r
```

instead of

```
val Date = "((\\d\\d)/(\\d\\d)/(\\d{4}))|((\\w{3}) (\\d\\d),\\s?(\\d{4}))".r
```

Not a large difference really but making regex's simpler is usually appreciated.

Comment: this is incorrect. `raw"..."` is needed to [ignore escape characters](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html).

Comment: @fommil, String interpolation came late to Scala (Scala 2.10.0). Triple quoting was and still is a way of expressing raw Strings.

Comment: I've had this sometimes work and sometimes fail for me. Can you reference an authoritative source that says it escapes backslashes?

Comment: I can't reproduce the "not working for me" case... I'll upvote you :-P Can you edit your answer so I can change my vote? (adding a reference would be good)

Comment: I reproduced! It is when doing `s"""$blah \ something"""` that the rawness breaks.

Comment: @fommil Take a look at Section 5.2 of Programming in Scala (2nd Ed.), the triple quoted form is explained there.