# Scala: how to flatten a List of a Set of filepaths

Tags: list, scala, set

I have a `List[Set[Path]]`: 
 **Update**: Each Path in a Set is unique and represents a particular directory location. There are no duplicates. So, what I am looking for is the total number of path elements/

```
val miceData = List(Set(C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory\Test7.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory\Test2.txt,     C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory\Test6.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory\Test5.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory\Test8.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory\Test3.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\aPowerPoint.pptx,     C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory\Test1.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory\Test4.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory2\Test10.txt),    Set(C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory2\Test6.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory2\Test3.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory2\Test4.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory2\Test70.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory2\Test8.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory2\Test5.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory2\Test2.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\FlatDirectory\Test2.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\FlatDirectory\Test3.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\FlatDirectory\Test1.txt), Set(C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\FlatDirectory\Test80.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\FlatDirectory\Test7.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\FlatDirectory\Test40.txt, C:\Users\lulu\Documents\GitHub\data_mining_folder\FlatDirectory\Test6.txt,     C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\FlatDirectory\Test5.txt), Set(C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\zipfile.zip), Set(C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\micetest.txt,C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\riley.jpg))
```

There are 5 `Sets` in this `List`, each `Set` holding `Path(s)`. The total number of such `Paths` is  28, if I counted correctly.

Now, I want to find out the total number of `Path` elements across all `Sets` in this `List`.

I could have done this computation in an area of my code upstream, but I am curious to do so now, and learn more  about Scala in the process.

Something like:

```
val totalPaths = <<iterate over this List and count all the paths>>
```

I would like the shortest, most idiomatic piece of code to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

```
val totalPaths = miceData.map(_.size).sum
```

If you have duplicates, you can do :

```
val totalPaths = miceData.flatten.distinct.size
```

Comment: you probably meant .size, not .count

Comment: Yes, size, if there are duplicates and in this case I have no duplicates.

Comment: This is the shortest answer you guys have given  me that works.

Answer (score 2):

```
val paths = for {              //gives you a list of all paths on all sets
    set <- miceData
    path <- set
   } yield path


val totalPaths = paths.toSet.size    // converting it to set will remove duplicates if any
```

Comment: Okay, this may be the solution I want, but let me test it out first.

Answer (score 2):

I think flatten is just enough

```
val toto = List(Set(1,2,3), Set(6,7,8))
println(toto.flatten.count)
```

Comment: Your answer has the benefit that it comes with an example to help me understand. I am going to test this out though, before deciding whose answer is the best suited for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
val totalPaths = miceData.flatten.size
```

OR

```
val totalPaths = miceData.flatten.length
```

And you might want to give your paths as triple qouted Strings. because with single quotes REPL is giving the following error.

```
<console>:1: error: invalid escape character
       List(Set("C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory\Test7.txt", "C:\Users\lulu\Documents\mice_data\data_mining_folder\DeeplyNestedDirectory\FlatDirectory\Test2.txt")).flatten.size
```

Comment: I am running my code as an SBT project inside IntelliJ. Double quotes should be good, you think?

Comment: Nope, Triple Quote is necessary. doesn't work with double qoutes. for more info refer to this ques http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024245/why-does-intellij-idea-offer-to-enclose-a-string-literal-to-triple-double-quotes